# How to prevent domain mirroring?

Tags: seo, domains, webserver

**My URL** = `https://mydomainurl.com/example-post`

**URL B** = `https://mirroringurl.com/cdn/example-post`

All HTML code at "URL B" is the same as the one at my URL, and when I change anything at my site, "URL B" will be refreshed to be again the same as my site (but not immediately, I do not know after how long "URL B" will be refreshed)

And people maintaining "URL B" can change CSS colors, brand/author name text, ads code.

I tried adding this script:

```
// Blocking 1 
if (parent.frames.length > 0) { parent.location.href = self.document.location } 

// Block 2 
var domain = "mydomainurl.com"; <--- at this they auto change my domain to their domain

var redirect = "http://google.com"; if( (location.hostname != domain) && (location.hostname != "www."+domain) ) { location.href = redirect; }
```

After I checked, I think they always recrawl when I update the post, or after 1 hours maybe?

> My solution encrypt script above, so their site can't rewrite my domain

Comment: i already set script // block 2 with encrypted so he can't auto change my domain, and now already redirect to google,

my question, will it still hurt my seo ? because page still alive just redirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is, Google should be able to recognize that you published the content first, meaning their copy is of less value. Be sure that you have some way to verify when your changes are published, such as pinging Google automatically when pages are updated, or marking last-updated timestamps on all of your pages, which can be automated in most CMSs. By having the earlier "last modified" date on your pages, Google and other bots can recognize that you are the one who published first and deserves the credit for the content.

You should also file a [DMCA takedown request](https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905?hl=en) since they are violating copyright law.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact the webmaster of URL B and mention that it is illegal to copy your content.

Also, you can take it down as @WebElaine suggested via [Google DMCA takedown](https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905?hl=en) request.

Are you sure they are crawling your site and not fetching your posts/content via RSS feeds?